# Prove $\forall x,c \in \mathbb R, |f(x) - f(c)| \le K|x - c|^2$ implies $f(x)$ is constant.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

The problem asks

> Given $f: \mathbb R \mapsto \mathbb R, K \in \mathbb R > 0$
>
> Prove $\forall x,c \in \mathbb R, |f(x) - f(c)| \le K|x - c|^2$ implies $f(x)$ is constant.

There's a hint in the prompt that says

> Hint: Using the definition find the derivative

Which I know is

$$\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} = L$$

but I'm not quite sure what to do with it. Then, I was thinking maybe a proof by contradiction that $f(x)$ is not constant, which would then mean $f'(x) > 0$, and by the mean value theorem $|f(x) - f(c)| > 0$, but then I wasn't really sure what to do with that. Basically, I don't really know how to approach the problem, and would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that,

$$ 0 \leq \lim_{x \to c} \left | \dfrac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c} \right | \leq \lim_{x \to c}{K |x-c|} \leq 0 $$

$$\implies f'(c) = 0 \ \forall \ c \quad \text{(By squeeze theorem) } $$

Therefore, $f$ is a constant function.

Comment: Only if we assume that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @Michael Where did we assume continuity?

Answer (score 3):

If $|f(x) - f(c)| \le K|x - c|^2$, then $$\frac{|f(x) - f(c)|}{|x-c|} \le K|x - c|$$
Taking the limit of the left hand side $ x \rightarrow c$ gives you the derivative, and then apply the sandwich theorem with the inequality, since the limit of the RHS of the inequality is zero.